# Unselect item from listbox from pysimplegui

Tags: python, python-3.x, listbox, listboxitem, pysimplegui

The question pretty straight forward. When I click on an item from the listbox it opens another window with information and buttons. However after closing that Window and hitting the search button (with or without values in names) it will open that window again due to still being selected I think. Below is a shortened version and runable program I'm using.

Update: using python version 3.8.2 pysimplegui version 4.55.1

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

name = ''
info_string = '' #created in create_string() to update text in secondary_gui()
list_index = 0 #created in user() to update user information in add_point()
choices = [] #created in search() to update listbox in main_gui()
index = [] #created in main_gui() to get that users information from dataframe by cross refrencing name
list_info = [] #created in user() to get list of that users information
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'points'],
             data=np.array([['James', 2],
                            ['josh', 12],
                            ['charles', 5]
                            ]))

def maingui():
    global name
    global choices
    global index

    layout = [[sg.Text('name', size=(6, 1)), sg.Input(key='-Name-')],
              [sg.Button('Search'), sg.Button('Add user'), sg.Button('Close')],
              [sg.Listbox(choices, size=(51, len(choices)), key='-CName-', enable_events=True, bind_return_key=True)]
              ]

    window = sg.Window('users', layout)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        name = values['-Name-']

        if event == 'Close' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == 'Search':
            #find match using name
            search()
            #update listbox choices
            window['-CName-'].update(choices)
        #if event == '-CName-' and len(values['-CName-']):
        if values['-CName-']:
            #check information of user clicked from listbox
            index = values['-CName-']
            user()
            #window['-CName-'].enable_click_events = False
            #values['-CName-'] = False
            secondary_gui()
            #sg.popup('selected', values['-CName-'])



    window.close()

def secondary_gui():
    global info_string
    create_string()
    layout = [[sg.Text(info_string, key='-CInfo-')],
              [sg.Button('Add Point')]]

    window = sg.Window('user Information', layout)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == 'Close' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

    window.close()

def search():
    print('search')
    global name
    global choices
    global df

    df1 = df
    # find name in gsheet
    if name:
        df1 = df1.loc[df1['name'].str.contains(name, case=False)]
        print(name)
        print(df1)
    # create list that GUI can read properly
    cdf = df1.values.tolist()
    choices = cdf

def user():
    print('user')
    global index
    global info_string
    global list_index
    global list_info
    global df
    global name

    # index is nested list, get correct values corresponding to list
    name = index[0][0]

    df1 = df
    # create list based on matching name
    df1 = df1.loc[df1['name'].str.contains(name, case=False)]

    # get user index used for when updating user information(add_point())
    list_index = df1.index  #used in function not shown
    # create list of user to update user values(add_point())
    list_info = df1.stack().to_list()
    print(list_info)

def create_string():
    global info_string
    global list_info
    print('creating string')
    print(list_info)

    # create string for usergui window text
    info_string = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in list_info])
    print(info_string)

maingui()
```

I've tried setting  `values['-CName-'] = False`, using `sg.popup` instead of a window. Updated the enable_click_events to False on line 47. No luck.

I checked the [listbox demo program](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Listbox_Search_Filter.py) on github which doesnt have this issue. The difference that stood out to me was

`if event == '-LIST-' and len(values['-LIST-']):` instead of `if values['-CName-']:` but that didn't seem to work in my case when I swapped out -LIST- for -CName-.

My other idea is to somehow use tkinter and use its functions in here

Comment: Secondary window does not pop up. When is it supposed to be called into action?

Comment: secondary window does pop up after clicking one of the items in the list, as it should. it closes normally as well. but if i hit the search button in the first window, it pops up again.

Comment: after closing it for the second time. hitting the search button doesnt cause the second window to open up again. the difference between closing it the first time and the second time is that an item is selected in the list box the first time. (its set to show dark background if item is selected) and the second time its not

Comment: No matter what I do, I cant get the second window to open, ever. A few things I notices. First, line 28 (listbox = window['-CName'], the key is missing a dash - I personally dont like using those dashes before and after the key name, I often forget one or another. I capitalize my keys across the board. Easy to visualize them. 

Second, also in line 28, the listbox variable is not linked to anything. 
Third, the values in line 64 (event, values = window.read())  are not linked to anything either.

Comment: thats weird, i just copy pasted the above code to make sure i didnt delete something i shouldnt have. and it runs just like it has been this whole time. line 28 is commented out. i forgot to delete that, i was trying something else but it didnt lead to anything useful.

Comment: line 64 looks for event 'Close' which is what i normaly use as my exit button. im not currently using a close button in this code to keep it simple. but it also looks for event sg.WIN_CLOSED which is what closes when you hit the little X in the top right corner of the window and breaking the while loop.

Comment: When I hit search, it prints in terminal the name and points, but no window pops up. When I hit add, nothing happens at all. It must be because of what I mentioned in my previous comment, as listbox (line 28) and events (line 64) do not link to anything.

Comment: when you hit search it should print names inside of the listbox bellow the 'search' and 'add user', and 'close' button. the 'Add User' Button isnt linked to anything because again i wanted to keep it simple, just forgot to remove that. 

Line 64 is linked to Line 66 and Line 28 is commented out. not used.

Comment: @RobinSage to open a window click on one of the names in the listbox

Comment: Ok, I see. So, I click on a name, and then the add points window pops up. Nothing gets added because obviously it's not coded, so no problems here. Then, when I close it out, another window (selected)  pops up. When I click to close it, it closes. I repeat the the actions, and it does it all again. Sorry, but I dont get what the problem is.

Comment: right all of that is good. the problem is after closing that second window. if you click search on the first window, the second window pops up again without clicking on any of the names, which it shouldnt be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the programming logic,

```py
        if values['-CName-']:
```

This statement in event loop will be executed no matter when event is, besides events `sg.WIN_CLOSED` and `'Close'`, that's why it will popup secondary gui after you click search.

When you click search button first time, this if will be false, so no popup window.

If it is specified for event `'-CName-'` to popup secondary window, you may need to specify it to

```py
        elif event == '-CName-' and values['-CName-']:
```

It means listbox clicked and with some item(s) selected.

If you need to unselect item from listbox,

```py
window[listbox_key].update(set_to_index=[])
```